# Build a video from UIImages problems

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, photo

I want to create a movie from an array of UIImages. I tried this code:

```
-(void)writeImageAsMovie:(UIImage*)image toPath:(NSString*)path size:(CGSize)size          duration:(int)duration 
{
NSError *error = nil;
AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                          error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];
AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                    assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                    outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                 assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
[videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

//Start a session:
[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

//Write samples:
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [Utils pixelBufferFromCGImage:image.CGImage size:size];
[adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];
[adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(duration-1, 2)];

//Finish the session:
[writerInput markAsFinished];
[videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(duration, 2)];
[videoWriter finishWriting];
}
```

But the output isn't ok.

The image is like this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/screenshot20120921at140.png/

And video output is:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/screenshot20120921at140.png/

Comment: what errors you are getting?!!

Comment: None, but the output video is a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the size you gave for buffer.
try this size and see once:

```
buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[array objectAtIndex:0] CGImage] size:CGSizeMake(480, 320)];
```

Comment: I tried. That's not the problem. :(

I also tried this link: http://www.developers-life.com/create-movie-from-array-of-images.html . Same results!

Comment: the output video will be kinda mess if the size of your images are greater or smaller than the size you give .!!

Comment: All the images have the same size. I give for buffer the size of the image: [self writeImageAsMovie:image toPath:myPathDocs size:image.size duration:1];

Answer (score 0):

try this
https://github.com/meslater/MSImageMovieEncoder